# configure wxWidgets --with-wine: stuck on "checking where we are cross compiling..."

Tags: gcc, compilation, wxwidgets, cross-compiling, wine

I'm on Ubuntu Trusty, trying to run `./configure --with-wine` inside my wxWidgets source folder. First, I ran into the problem detailed here: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=7729.

So then I ran `export CFLAGS="-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"` to get `windows.h` and other files.

But now when I try `./configure --with-wine` again, it gets stuck on "checking whether we are cross compiling...". Here's a short snippet of config.log:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 
configure:16705: $? = 0
configure:16694: winegcc -V >&5
winegcc: option -V requires an argument
configure:16705: $? = 2
configure:16694: winegcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
winegcc: gcc failed
configure:16705: $? = 2
configure:16725: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:16747: winegcc -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include   conftest.c  >&5
configure:16751: $? = 0
configure:16799: result: yes
configure:16802: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:16804: result: a.out
configure:16810: checking for suffix of executables
configure:16817: winegcc -o conftest -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include   conftest.c  >&5
configure:16821: $? = 0
configure:16843: result: .exe
configure:16865: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:16873: winegcc -o conftest.exe -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include   conftest.c  >&5
In file included from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:9,
                 from conftest.c:10:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw.h:238:0: warning: "__int64" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define __int64 long long
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

Without using --with-wine, it runs successfully. However, upon `make`, I get:

```
cd ../src/stc && ./gen_iface.py
/bin/sh: 1: ./gen_iface.py: Permission denied
make: *** [../include/wx/stc/stc.h] Error 126
```

Same thing happens if I try `sudo make`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use WINE and not just cross-compile normally? To be honest, I have no idea why would you ever user `--with-wine`, it doesn't seem to make much sense to me...

Comment: It was documented here: ftp://biolpc22.york.ac.uk/pub/2.8.2/install-wine-2.8.2.txt

Comment: Updated question with additional problem after `./configure` without --with-wine

Answer (score 0):

The `gen_iface.py` error might be due to not having Python on your system. If you do have it, the only explanation I see is that the file itself is somehow not executable on your system, do `chmod +x src/stc/gen_iface.py` to change it in this case.

Also notice that running `--with-wine` or cross-compiling and building natively are completely different things, you almost certainly need to ask yourself what are you really trying to do and make sure you understand the difference between them.

Comment: I want to have a GHC that targets windows from linux host. On the other hand I thought if I had ghc installed with wine, I would use wine ghc to compile my app and it would work similarly. I don't know what --with-wine does.

Running `chmod +x ...gen_iface.py` causes the error "No such file or directory" upon trying to run the file.

Comment: If you want to target Windows, you need to cross-compile, i.e. run configure with the appropriate `--host=i686-mingw32` or similar argument. As for the error with `chmod`, it looks impossible, sorry. The file is clearly there, otherwise you wouldn't be getting a "permission denied" error for it, so you're either nor running the command in the correct directory or made a typo in it.

Comment: using the --host option, I get `configure: error: wxWidgets requires wchar_t support.`

Comment: Note that is after setting my CFLAGS="-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include", otherwise it'll tell me to set my CFLAGS to find windows.h

Comment: Please check that you have a functional cross-compiler. You shouldn't have to set `CFLAGS` manually, this is very error-prone. If you get errors from configure, `config.log` is the place to find more details about them.

Answer (score 0):

OK I ran into a similar issue, though it was with cross compile configuring seemingly unrelated libraries (ffmpeg dependencies in my case) (gets stuck at "checking if we are cross compiling" typically, sometimes other places, always when it's running `./conftest.exe` or sometimes `wine64 conftest.exe`).

After that point, neither win32 nor win64 .exe's run under wine, everything "just hangs" (before that, it works fine).  Even rebooting the whole linux box hangs (ai ai).  It also seems impossible to kill a process called `/usr/bin/wineserver` even with `sudo kill -9 ...` odd.

Temporary work around: remove wine package or possibly disable its [auto-run console functionality](https://askubuntu.com/q/344088/20972).

Seemed like it only failed for me with win64 exe's though not sure there (running 15.10, wine 1.6.2, also accompanied by kernel BUG failure in big_memory.c or some odd, and "cpu stall for 32s" failures so possibly my system is bworked [virtualbox]) so if you still need wine you might be able to install it "32 bit only" (untested, non trivial).